# TinyMCE: Custom characters for format?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to change the behaviour for the "BOLD" - Format. Instead of wrapping

```
<b>text</b>
```

around it, it should instead wrap

```
*text*
```

around it. I found examples to wrap other html-Tags than the default, but not how to wrap simple characters.

One of those examples: `bold: {inline: 'span', 'classes': 'bold'},`

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this isn't really possible without changing the library, making an undocumented library call or building some JS to hook into TinyMCE's output. Neither of these are options you should really consider; they could break as soon as you try and update the library. And being unable to update the library means you won't be able to opt into bugfixes and the like.

The API for custom formats is documented here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:formats

Is your intention to allow users to submit markdown formatted text to a server? If so, I wonder if you might have to perform reparsing. I know of one project that offers this: https://github.com/hgilani/html2markdown. Not sure if it suits your needs, though.

Comment: I just want to allow formatting like here on SO where "*" and "_" can be used for formatting

Comment: @OleAlbers - have you looked for any text editor libraries that already provide this functionality other than TinyMCE?

Comment: @OleAlbers https://github.com/lepture/editor - [Demo here](http://lab.lepture.com/editor/)